# How do I make a screen that pushes another screen like this? (Example: discord app)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to make a slidable screen in flutter. Should I use like a special version of Navigator.push?

the example in discord link here:
[image: the example in discord link here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Class for you want to do, and you can use this class on your navigator codes. This class not working like you want but it's just an example.

```
class BouncyPageRoute extends PageRouteBuilder{
  final Widget widget;

 BouncyPageRoute ({this.widget})
  :super(

  transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds:  850),
  transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
      Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secAnimation,
      Widget child){
    animation = CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animation, curve: Curves.bounceOut
    );
    return ScaleTransition(alignment: Alignment.center,
      scale:animation,
      child: child,
    );
  },

  pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secAnimation){
    return widget;
  }

 );
}
```

Comment: I've seen many animations like these before but these don't really help because the page goes on top of the other, but for mine, I need it to actually interact with one another

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a Drawer with custom left menu shape, you can use this, [flutter_inner_drawer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inner_drawer)

Set your offset for positioning and left child for a container with top right and bottom right corner border radius.

[UPDATED]
For the snap bottom navigation, you can achieve by show modalBottomSheet with sized when toggle the drawer, delay a second to show the modal if necessary, Navigator.pop(context) when close drawer:

```
   showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isDismissible: false,
      enableDrag: false,
      builder: (BuildContext builder) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          child: // your buttons
        );
      },
    );
```

Or,

Create a slide container, [slide_container](https://pub.dev/packages/slide_container), shows when drawer open.

Comment: Yes, this helps a little bit. thanks! but do you know how to also get the button menu to pop up once the drawer is open?

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/blackmann/overlapping_panels

But the idea is to use a `Stack` with the topmost widget being a `GestureDetector` to detect drags and translate the widgets below based on the drag offset.